# VBA Loop Not Pasting Correctly from Excel

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I've created a macro that uses 5 columns to paste data into SAP GUI using a loop. However, once it gets to row 30 or 40, it stops pasting the data correctly where it pastes the same number. Not sure if I should add something to enhance the code? All responses will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim Application
If Not IsObject(Application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If
i = 2
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtGV_MATNR").Text = Cells(i, 1)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtGV_WERKS").Text = Cells(i, 2)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtGV_WERKS").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtGV_WERKS").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtZIP_MM02_STRUCTURE-EISBE_P").Text = Cells(i, 3)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtZIP_MM02_STRUCTURE-EISBE_RD").Text = Cells(i, 4)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtZIP_MM02_STRUCTURE-EISBE_RD").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtZIP_MM02_STRUCTURE-EISBE_RD").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtZIP_MM02_STRUCTURE-EISBE_RD").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[21]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTEXTEDIT/shellcont/shell").Text = Cells(i, 5) + vbCr + "" + vbCr + ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTEXTEDIT/shellcont/shell").setSelectionIndexes 99, 99
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess there is an error sent by SAP GUI so, first of all, please remove the line `On Error Resume Next` (it's used to ignore the errors), and tell us the error message, and at what line it occurs.

Comment: Like SandraRossi said, change the error handling to output the error so it's not being ignored. Also, if you say row 30 or 40 -- is there a different value in those rows? Anything details about the data you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your solution is that the control showing table wont let you access basicaly anything further than what is visible (not actually true, another 3 or so rows may be loaded into memory though).

What you need to do is to refresh the table either by using the "Next Page (Page down)" button from the upper bar of SAP GUI or manipulate the scrollbar.

Either way, remember that the row index will reset back to the beginning so you would need to reset your counter too.

You may find it easier to not contain all the code in On Error Resume Next too.

Example for one of the kinds of shell tables:

```
    For i = 0 To session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell").rowcount - 1
        
        session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell").firstVisibleRow = i

    Next
```